# find possible values

Tags: combinatorics

$abcd=-2020$ Find all possible 4-tuples of $a,b,c,d$
So I tried to count this one by one but I think the cases were just too many to consider, I was trying to find a way of doing this quicker. Is there any insight toward how to do this fast? I know this question may seem dumb to ask but help will really be appreciated!

Comment: Have you found the prime factorization of $2020$?

Comment: yes but there are too many factors; for example I can put 2 into the a spot and 10 into the 10th spot and reverse it; there just seems to be a lot of possibilities.

Comment: Since $2020 = 2^2 \cdot 5 \cdot 101$, each factor has the form $2^x5^y101^z$.  If $x_k$ is the exponent of $2$ in the $k$th factor, then $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 2$, where $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4$ are nonnegative integers.  You also have to account for the exponents of $5$ and $101$.  Since $-2020 < 0$, an odd number of the factors must be negative.

Comment: @Guy who failed everything I wanted to ask whether my answer is correct or not? Could you please check it out once if you know the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$2020=101*2^2*5$$
Now use star and bars for the powers of prime factors.  For example for $101$
$$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=1$$

For this we get number of solutions as $\binom {4}{3}$

Similarly for $2$ we have 
$$y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4=2$$ and 
get number of solutions as $\binom {5}{3}$ and for $5$ we have 
$$z_1+z_2+z_3+z_4=1$$ 
and get number of solutions as $\binom {4}{3}$.

We need to also consider which of the numbers is negative.

Hence an odd number of the factors must be negative. For this we have the ways to select negative integers as $\binom {4}{3}+ \binom {4}{1}$

Hence the number of solutions would be
$$\binom {4}{3}.\binom {5}{3}.\binom {4}{3}. \left[\binom {4}{3}+ \binom {4}{1}\right]=1280 $$

Comment: why the downvote? Is the answer wrong?